# Aclad sheet metal P/N 22024T3

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

I am looking for aclad sheet metal  P/N 22024T3   2MM, 1.2MM AND 1.6MM 1 SQM each. Anyone could help me locate those? I sent requestes to MROs etc, most do not recognize the P/N which is taken from the AIRBUS A320 AMM.  Help, anyonme. I would porefer to find it in Europe if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra 2 in the P/N. Check [2024T3 ALCLAD ALUMINUM SHEET](http://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/mepages/alumsheet_2024t3.php) on aircraftspruce.com.

Double check the AMM and recontact your suppliers.

Comment: Also, it's not a part number. 2024 is the code of a specific aluminium alloy. T3 indicates the tempering method (heat treatment). Alclad means there is a pure aluminium cladding on top of the sheet for corrosion protection.